# Xbox 1 Controller sound while recording

Tags: audio, recording

I currently use an Audio-Technica ATR2500-USB Cardioid Condenser USB Microphone with a shock mount, pop filter, and Mudder Large Foam Mic Windscreen for MXL, Audio Technica.

I record using Nvidia Shadowplay with the mic about 3 inches from my mouth with the volume on the Mic set to 65 (in the playback devices menu).

How can I record my audio commentary and not pick up the controller joysticks/buttons like other individuals, I post my material to youtube.

I have tangled with the volume on the mic and whether it's at 10 or 100, it always picks up the controller.

Comment: The title does not reveal much information about your problem or what you actually wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

A typical solution is to create better acoustic isolation between your keyboard/controller and the microphone.  The thing that really stops sound waves is not foam itself, but mass.  Eight ounces of foam is nothing compared to 8 lbs of rigid fiberglass.

Another solution is to use a downward expander.  This audio-processing device (which can be an external analog box or a digital plug-in) can be programmed so that an audio "gate" is closed unless a signal is both loud enough and lasts long enough to open it.  The click of a key would not be enough to open it, but a human voice speaking words would.  While you are talking, the clicks could come through, but they will be masked by the voice, and hopefully not too distracting in that case.